# Trying to grab value from html page but getting template back not the value - php

Tags: php, html, server-side

I am making a price crawler for a project but am running into a bit of an issue. I am using the below code to extract values from an html page:

```
$content = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
$resultsArray = array();
$sqlresult = array();

$priceElement = explode( '<div>value I want to extract</div>' , $content );
```

Now when I use this to get certain elements I only get back

```
Finance: {{value * value2}}
```

I want to get the actual value that would be displayed on the screen e.g

```
Finance: 7.96
```

The other php methods I have tried are:

curl

```
file_get_html(using simple_html_dom library)
```

None of these work either :( Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You just set the `<div>value I want to extract</div>` as a delimiter, which means PHP looks for it to separate your string to array whenever this occurs.

In the following code we use `,` character as a delimiter:

```
<?php
$string = "apple,banana,lemon";
$array = explode(',', $string);
echo $array[1];
?>
```

The output should be this:

```
banana
```

In your example you set the value you want to extract as a delimiter. That's why this happens to you. You'll need to set a delimiter between your string you want to obtain and other string you won't need at the moment.

For example:

```
<?php
$string = "iDontNeedThis-dontExtractNow-value I want to extract-dontNeedEither";
$priceElement = explode('-', $string);
echo "<div>".$priceElement[2]."</div>";
?>
```

The code should output this to your HTML page:

```
<div>value I want to extract</div>
```

And it will appear on your page like this:

```
value I want to extract
```

If you don't need to save the whole array in a variable, you can save the one index of it to variable instead:

```
$priceElement = explode('-', $string)[2];
echo $priceElement;
```

This will save only `value I want to extract` so you won't have to deal with arrays later on.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question although much appreciated. Its the fact that the raw data I receive from the function file_get_contents, gives me the value as <div>{{variable * variable2}}</div> not <div>7.96</div> if you see what i mean. I can extract it and return it to the front end, the issue is that I am not getting the right information from crawling the page.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry, I don't know how to work with raw data.